# What is the purpose of using static on a constant in a Swift structure?

Tags: swift, constants, keychain

While following a tutorial on using the Keychain feature, I noticed a section of code where I needed to implement a structure as the following:

```
// Keychain Configuration
struct KeychainConfiguration {
  static let serviceName = "TouchMeIn"
  static let accessGroup: String? = nil
}
```

I know that a *constant* property on a value type can't be modified once instantiated so I was curious of the purpose of using static in this sense?

**P.S.**
This question is not similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37701187/when-to-use-static-constant-and-variable-in-swift) because the highest accepted answer (which I would think is the best answer) doesn't provide enough detail or any pros or cons.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use static constant and variable in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37701187/when-to-use-static-constant-and-variable-in-swift)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the use of “static” keyword if “let” keyword used to define constants/immutables in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34574876/what-is-the-use-of-static-keyword-if-let-keyword-used-to-define-constants-im)

Comment: The post by @Cristik I think gave more detail as to how the static variable can be used as a type property.

Comment: You don't have to initialize your struct to access methods or variables that are declared static. You can call them globally via your struct name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has multiple applications, including but not limited by the following:

1) To give a constant separate namespace, if constants have same names.

```
struct A {
    static let width: Int = 100
}

struct B {
    static let width: Int = 100
}
print(A.width)
print(B.width)
```

2) Static constants are 'lazy' by design, so if you are about to use lazy-behaved global constant, it might be handy to put it in a structure.

3) To show your coworkers that constant is applicable to specific domain where given structure is used.

4) Organize your configuration in sections:`Theme.Layout.itemHeight` or `Label.Font.avenirNext`

Comment: Actually, enums are better candidates for namespacing.

Comment: @Cristik doesn't cancel the fact, that structures are also used for that.

Comment: @llb You wouldn't use a spoon to eat noodles when you have chopsticks.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri could I have place the code in my question above into an enum since they are strings?  I tried this but didn't have much luck.  Could you provide an example?