# Random Number Generator in url

Tags: ios, swift, random

I currently have a random number generator in my url that is used to assign new numbers to the page parameter of the url. When I fetch a new image and print the url, it uses the same url. I do not know how to approach removing the existing random number in the url.

Here is my declaration:

```
public static var random = Int.random(in: 0..<450)
static let ImageURL = "https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos/?client_id=\(UnsplashClient.apiKey)&page=\(random))"
```

Comment: `var imageURL: String { "https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos/?client_id=\(UnsplashClient.apiKey)&page=\(Int.random(in: 0..<450)))" }`

Comment: @LeoDabus thank you for the response. This did help, I had confusions about the use of static

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 1):

Do not use static for your array. Static variables only generated once. So it does not generate random numbers for you.
read this: [When to use static constant and variable in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37701187/when-to-use-static-constant-and-variable-in-swift)

Comment: "Static variables only generated once" ??? This has nothing to do with being declared static or not https://stackoverflow.com/a/56762161/2303865

Answer (score 0):

According to me, You have to create a array of numbers that contains integers from 0 to 450 like this `var array = Array(0...450)` and and then can select random number from that array using `array.randomElement()!`. And after selecting, remove that number from that array.

Comment: it would be better to randomize an index and get the element when you remove it. `if let index =  array.indices.randomElement() {`
    `let value = array.remove(at: index)`
`}`

Comment: Considering the low probability of repeating a random value I don't think it would be necessary to remove the value from the array. This way OP doesn't need to check if the array is empty to fill it up again

Comment: Yes the probability is very less but as per the question requirement, I added this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a `static property` and it's value is not gonna change each time you call it, unless you update it manually. You can fix this issue by using `static computed property` whose value is computed everytime it's used.

```
public static var random: Int { .random(in: 0..<450) }
public static var ImageURL: String { "https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos/?client_id=\(UnsplashClient.apiKey)&page=\(random))" }
```

Or you can combine them as @leo has mentioned in the comments, if you don't have any other purpose for `random`, like this:

```
public static var imageURL: String { "https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos/?client_id=\(UnsplashClient.apiKey)&page=\(Int.random(in: 0..<450)))" }
```

Comment: This won't make a difference. ImageURL is constanrt. random will only be called once

Comment: Thanks! How could I forget that?